# Split Json object into multiple json objects in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

I'm a newbie to PHP and I want to split a json object that I have stored in a variable into multiple json objects.

My input looks like this :

```
{
   "results":[
      {
         "id":"001",
         "items":{
            "item11":"value1",
            "item12":"value2",
            "item13":"value3"
          },
      {
         "id":"002",
         "items":{
            "item21":"value1",
            "item22":"value2",
            "item23":"value3"
          },
      {
         "id":"003",
         "items":{
            "item31":"value1",
            "item32":"value2",
            "item33":"value3"
          }]
}
```

I want to first extract each id and store it into a variable and associate to each id the correspondant json that will look like this :

```
$id1 = "001";

{
       "item11":"value1",
       "item12":"value2",
       "item13":"value3"
 }
```

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do. How do you expect to "associate to each id the correspondant json"?

Comment: In other words, I'm trying to have each items related to an id stored in a separate object

Comment: Seems like you would just need to decode the JSON and restructure the array. Makes no sense to create a bunch of dynamically named variables. You would want the id as the array key and the object as a value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this loop over each record and save it in result.

```
$json=json_decode($str,true);

array_map(function($value) use (&$results){
    $results[$value['id']]=json_encode($value['items']);
    return $results;
}
,$json['results']);

print_r($results);
```

output

```
Array ( 
[001] => {"item11":"value1","item12":"value2","item13":"value3"} 
[002] => {"item21":"value1","item22":"value2","item23":"value3"} 
[003] => {"item31":"value1","item32":"value2","item33":"value3"} )
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to display every array item in `results`, you can use `extract($arr['results'])`

but if you want to have specific name you should use loops to do it, depend on your pattren